# Methods won't run from another class within Main

Tags: java

I can't seem to figure out why my second class 'ZooAuthenticator' can't run my other methods created in my first class, 'authentiClass'. It seems to be able to run the main method from the main method within authentiClass but that's about it. Please help, I'm almost done with this program and I can't figure out why this is happening.

```
package zooauthenticator;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

class authentiClass {



    public void sysStart1(){
        System.out.println("--System Startup Sequence Now Loading--");
    }
    public void sysStart2(){
        System.out.println(". . .");
    }
    public void sysStart3(){
        System.out.println("Loaded!");
    }
    public void sysStart4(){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Central Zoo Keeping System!");
        System.out.println("Admins and Users can log in below.");
    }




    private String original;
    private String value;
    private String value2;
    private static String passwordToHash;
    private static String generatedPassword;
    public void authentiUser() throws java.io.IOException{
        System.out.println("Enter Active Username: ");

        BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        value = bufferRead.readLine();
        System.out.println(value);

        System.out.println("Enter Active Password: ");

        value2 = bufferRead.readLine();
        System.out.println(value2);

        String adminPass = "letmein";
        String adminPass2 = "animal doctor";
        String vetPass = "secret password";
        String vetPass2 = "grizzly1234";
        String zooPass = "alphabet soup";
        String zooPass2 = "M0nk3y business";


        if (value2.equals(zooPass) || value2.equals(zooPass2)){
            System.out.println("Logged in!");
            System.out.println("Hello, Zookeeper!\n" +
            "\n" +
            "As zookeeper, you have access to all of the animals' information and their daily "
            + "monitoring logs. This allows you to track their feeding habits, habitat "
            + "conditions, and general welfare.");
            System.out.println("Press 0 to log out");
            Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
            int c = choice.nextInt();

            if (c == 0){
            System.out.println("Logged out.");
            }
        }else{

        }


        if (value2.equals(vetPass) || value2.equals(vetPass2)){
            System.out.println("Logged in!");
            System.out.println("Hello, Veterinarian!\n" +
            "\n" + "As veterinarian, you have access to all of the animals' health records. "
            + "This allows you to view each animal's medical history and current "
            + "treatments/illnesses (if any), and to maintain a vaccination log.");
            System.out.println("Press 0 to log out");
            Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
            int c = choice.nextInt();

            if (c == 0){
            System.out.println("Logged out.");
            }
        }else{

        }

        if (value2.equals(adminPass) || value2.equals(adminPass2)){
        System.out.println("Logged in!");
        System.out.println("Hello, System Admin!\n" +
        "\n" +
        "As administrator, you have access to the zoo's main computer system.");  
        System.out.println("This allows you to monitor users in the system and their roles.");
        System.out.println("Press 0 to log out");
        Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
        int c = choice.nextInt();

        if (c == 0){
            System.out.println("Logged out.");
        }
        }else{

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException 
    {
        passwordToHash = "password";
        generatedPassword = null;
        try {
            // Create MessageDigest instance for MD5
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            //Add password bytes to digest
            md.update(passwordToHash.getBytes());
            //Get the hash's bytes 
            byte[] bytes = md.digest();
            //This bytes[] has bytes in decimal format;
            //Convert it to hexadecimal format
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i=0; i< bytes.length ;i++)
            {
                sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }
            //Get complete hashed password in hex format
            generatedPassword = sb.toString();
        } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(generatedPassword);
    }
}

class ZooAuthenticator {
    public void main (String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException{
        new authentiClass().sysStart1();
        new authentiClass().sysStart2();
        new authentiClass().sysStart3();
        new authentiClass().sysStart4();
        new authentiClass().authentiUser();
        new authentiClass().main(args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ZooAuthenticator your main method should be static.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a object for that class and access the methods with that object.

```
authentiClass obj = new authentiClass();
obj.sysStart1();
obj.sysStart2();
obj.sysStart3();
obj.sysStart4();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a particulat format which java looks for launching class, when you run "java Classname"
Java looks for main method inside the given "Classname" as you are invoking from outside without the object created the method should be public and static. And it always looks for array of String[] arguments in the main method.

public static void main(String args[]) {

}

ZooAuthenticator is missing this format